# PagedList MVC Show only page numbers which are greater than current Page number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, pagedlist

I have created pagination for an mvc project using PagedList, all ok until a new requirement came in:

- 1st Page: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 Next
- 2nd Page: Previous 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 Next [**Numbers ascend as user views
  more pages**]
- 3rd Page: Previous 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 Next [**Numbers ascend as user views
  more pages**]

Is there a way to do this? I have checked PagedListRenderOptions(), could not find a property for this.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I saw no one answered this, even it's almost one year old. I've got the same issue today.

In the view where you create the pages. Default the code looks like this

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
                     new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Method PagedListPager has an other overload where you can put `PagedListRenderOptions`

So the final code should look like this if you want 3 pages to be shown.

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
                     new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }), new PagedListRenderOptions {
                         DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Never,
                         DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Never,
                         DisplayLinkToPreviousPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
                         DisplayLinkToNextPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
                         MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 3
                     }))
```

Edit :

here is where I got my inspiration from:

https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions.cs